# Is it possible to extract data in a specified format (similar to outline format in pivot tables in Excel)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extract about 500,000 rows covering invoice number, invoice date, and invoice lines from a database in a specified format:

From this

| Invoice Number | Date | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Jan 1 | Apple |
| 001 | Jan 1 | Banana |
| 001 | Jan 1 | Carrot |
| 002 | Jan 1 | Apple |
| 002 | Jan 1 | Banana |
| 002 | Jan 1 | Carrot |

To this

| Invoice Number | Date | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Jan 1 | Apple |
| ---- | ---- | Banana |
| ---- | ---- | Carrot |
| 002 | Jan 1 | Apple |
| ---- | ---- | Banana |
| ---- | ---- | Carrot |

Is this possible with just a query in SQL (or does this formatting need to be performed in Excel)? If possible, the query would be appreciated.

Comment: This is doable in SQL but preferably you apply a formatting in a presentation level. Tag your DBMS if you still want a SQL solution.

Comment: Presumably you want to invoice number and/or date to appear again when they change, right? You should probably add a second invoice just to make that clear.

Comment: SQL is a query language, not a report engine. If you want to create an Excel sheet with specific formatting you can use a library like eg EPPlus to create an Excel file *and* pivot table using the query results. Using Excel for 500K rows is *not* a great idea though.

Comment: Yes, would like the invoice number and date to appear again when they change.

Comment: Thank you, will look up EPPlus.